# Can we request a change to the site CSS?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

*This is about basic HTML element styling, not our site's eventual graphic design.*

In [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/what-does-the-laundry-rpg-change-in-the-brp/3341#3341) we can see how list formatting is a little strange: there is a space before a sub-list but no space after the sub-list. This is the opposite of what how we'd expect sub-lists to be formatted.

Can we get this fixed? The below isn't extensively-tested code, but if something like this could be added to the site CSS:

```
ul p + ul {
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

…then list formatting would look much more natural. This removes the space between a list-item and a sub-list and adds a space after the same sub-list.

Comment: Bugs in the "beta" theme should be reported on [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126185/147191).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there won't be any changes permitted while the site is in beta, however if it makes it out of beta it will get a proper design - gaming and programmers are good examples of sites with their final full designs.

Jin (?), the SE designer will go through a process of proposing designs here on meta if that point comes and generally takes feedback and suggestions on-board (for instance the first programmers one was completely scrapped based on the initial comments).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I look at that answer and is seems a little irregular... using only Markdown syntax I get the following, and it doesn't include any of the `<p>` elements which are creating the space between... did [@Matt Sheridan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/556/matt-sheridan) manually enter his own HTML?

> - **Charisma stat** replaces Appearance
> - **No Magic Points**
> - **Personality Type** is selected during character creation, adding an additional 20 skill points which are distributed between specific personality-appropriate skills. Personality choices include:
>
>   - Bruiser
>   - Leader
>   - Master (as in craftsman)
>   - Nutter (also starts with an insanity)
>   - Slacker
>   - Thinker
> - **Laundry Assignment/Training** is selected during character creation. Grants +10 bonus to several skills. (This is in addition to Call of Cthulhu-style professions.) Choices include:
>
>   - Archives
>   - Computational Demonology
>   - Contracts and Bindings
>   - Counter-Possession
>   - Counter-Subversion
>   - Information Technology
>   - Media Relations
>   - Medical and Psychological
>   - Plumber (that being what the Laundry call their paramilitary clean-up operatives)
> - **Wealth Levels** instead of specific savings and income.
> - **Some changes to skill list**
> - The big mechanical change is apparently a **new magic system**. It covers traditional/ritual magic, Laundry-style computational magic, and "mental" magic (which is casting spells without external aid). As noted above, Magic Points are out, but casting now requires a skill check with a Sorcery skill.
> - **Combat and investigation are streamlined**, although I haven't seen anything about exactly how. Also, nice things were said about the sanity system.
> - **Special Successes** (rolling under 1/5 of your skill) replace criticals/impales. On attack rolls, they do double damage. Outside of combat, I think they're just extra good successes without any special rules.

... and the Markdown:

```
 - **Charisma stat** replaces Appearance
 - **No Magic Points**
 - **Personality Type** is selected during character creation, adding an additional 20 skill points which are distributed between specific personality-appropriate skills. Personality choices include:
  - Bruiser
  - Leader
  - Master (as in craftsman)
  - Nutter (also starts with an insanity)
  - Slacker
  - Thinker
 - **Laundry Assignment/Training** is selected during character creation. Grants +10 bonus to several skills. (This is in addition to Call of Cthulhu-style professions.) Choices include:
  - Archives
  - Computational Demonology
  - Contracts and Bindings
  - Counter-Possession
  - Counter-Subversion
  - Information Technology
  - Media Relations
  - Medical and Psychological
  - Plumber (that being what the Laundry call their paramilitary clean-up operatives)
 - **Wealth Levels** instead of specific savings and income.
 - **Some changes to skill list**
 - The big mechanical change is apparently a **new magic system**. It covers traditional/ritual magic, Laundry-style computational magic, and "mental" magic (which is casting spells without external aid). As noted above, Magic Points are out, but casting now requires a skill check with a Sorcery skill.
 - **Combat and investigation are streamlined**, although I haven't seen anything about exactly how. Also, nice things were said about the sanity system.
 - **Special Successes** (rolling under 1/5 of your skill) replace criticals/impales. On attack rolls, they do double damage. Outside of combat, I think they're just extra good successes without any special rules.
```

Comment: If you put a blank line between bullet elements, then you get `<p>` tags inside the `<li>` tags. I looked at his markdown source and that's what was happening.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - As such there's a workaround; don't put a blank line between... this makes it seem less likely that the team would develop a fix.

Comment: There is *supposed* to be a difference between lists with spaces and lists without, and it works fine normally. It's only when sub-lists are involved that it doesn't work. From a web designer perspective, this is an oversight, not a deliberate design choice. It's also trivial to fix since it's a styling issue, not a structural issue.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - This is true. Perhaps the request is best made on meta.stackoverflow?